# CVS: check out first file committed after date

Tags: date, cvs, vcs-checkout

I am processing a set of files and want to be able to pull the first commit *after* certain dates (as opposed to before a date, as in CVS's -D option). This will probably involve some sort of scripting. My ideas were:

- parse the cvs log for each file to get the appropriate revision numbers
- use the -D option to get the previous file, get that file's revision number (through cvs status or the file header), and then get the subsequent file

Parsing the logs looks the easiest way. Is there a CVS shortcut that I am missing or a clever way to do it that I don't know about?

Comment: Are you after the next absolute commit across all branches, or just the next commit on the current branch?

Comment: The repository doesn't have any branches; I'm looking for the next commit of a specified file after certain dates.
My solution was to parse the log message for the file (first option above). If there is a better way to do it, it'd be useful to know; otherwise, not to worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a CVS shortcut for this, so I parsed the log message for the file and found the first release after date xxx.